# How to save the Mobile Stepper progress on click of next button

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, material-ui

I want to save the progress state of Mobile Stepper, so that when user logged out, the user can resume from the place where he left. If progress bar is filled 2% then when next time the user login he should resume from 2% not from 0.
Here is the code:

```
    import React, { useState, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Typography, Grid, CircularProgress, Paper } from '@mui/material/';
import guardianOptions from '../../../constants/guardianOptions.js';
import studentClasses from '../../../constants/studentClasses.js';
import Stepper from '@mui/material/Stepper';
import Step from '@mui/material/Step';
import StepLabel from '@mui/material/StepLabel';
import MobileStepper from '@mui/material/MobileStepper';
import StepContent from '@mui/material/StepContent';
import { makeStyles, withStyles, createStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { purple } from '@mui/material/colors';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import useStyles from './styles';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormHelperText from '@mui/material/FormHelperText';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

const User= (props) => {
  const { activeStep: lastActiveStep, userId } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [guardianType, setGuardianType] = useState(0);
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(lastActiveStep || 0);


  const [guardianRelationOptions, setGuardianRelationOptions] = useState(0);
 
  const [guardianDetailsForm, setGuardianDetailsForm] = useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
   
    {}
  );

    const [studentDetailsForm, setStudentDetailsForm] = useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
    { s_firstName: '', s_lastName: '', s_age: '', s_class: '' }
  );
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function updateActiveStep() {
      // this is just pseudo code - whatever your endpoint looks like
      await window.fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/user/:userId', { 
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({activeStep})
      })
    }
    updateActiveStep()
  }, [activeStep]);
 
 
 function getSteps(){
  return [<b style={{color:'purple'}}>'Personal Details'</b>, 
  <b style={{color:'purple'}}>'Relation'</b>, 
  <b style={{color:'purple'}}>'Guardian Details'</b>]; 
 }

    const steps = getSteps();

  
    
    
  function onGuardianTypeChangeChange(event) {
    // setAge(event.target.value);
    setGuardianType(event.target.value);
    let _guardianRelationOptions = guardianOptions.find(options => options.value === event.target.value);
    setGuardianRelationOptions(_guardianRelationOptions.relationships);
  }


 


  const handleGuardianDeatilsInput = evt => {
    const name = evt.target.name;
    const newValue = evt.target.value;
    setGuardianDetailsForm({ [name]: newValue });
    
    
  };

  const handleGuardianDetailsSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let data = { guardianDetailsForm };
    props.onGuardianDetails(guardianDetailsForm)
    console.log(data + "new user");
  //  console.log( props.onGuardianDetails(guardianDetailsForm) + "gana bajao");
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep+1);
    setGuardianDetailsForm();
   
    
  }



  function getStepContent(step) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0: if (!props.user.s_firstName) {
        return (<div>
        <form id ="form-step0" className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleGuardianDetailsSubmit} noValidate autoComplete="off">
         
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            name="s_firstName"
            label="First Name"
            variant="outlined"
            defaultValue={guardianDetailsForm.s_firstName}
            onChange={handleGuardianDeatilsInput} />
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            name="s_lastName"
            label="Last Name"
            variant="outlined"
            defaultValue={guardianDetailsForm.s_lastName}
            onChange={handleGuardianDeatilsInput} />
          <TextField
            id="outlined-number"
            label="Age"
            name="s_age"
            defaultValue={guardianDetailsForm.s_age}
            type="number"
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
            onChange={handleGuardianDeatilsInput}
            variant="outlined"
          />
          <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl} 
          sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Class</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
              id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
              value={guardianDetailsForm.s_class}
              onChange={handleGuardianDeatilsInput}
              label="Class"
              name="s_class"
            >
              {studentClasses.map(c =>
                <MenuItem key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.name}</MenuItem>
              )}
            </Select>
            {/* <Button variant="contained" type="submit" color="primary" >NEXT</Button> */}

          </FormControl>
        </form>
      </div> )}
;
      case 1: if (!props.user.g_relationship) {
        return ( <div>
        <form id="form-step1" className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleGuardianDetailsSubmit} noValidate autoComplete="off">
       
          <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}
          sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Relationship</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
              id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
              onChange={onGuardianTypeChangeChange}
              label="Relationship"
            >
              {guardianOptions.map(type =>
                <MenuItem key={type.value} value={type.value}>{type.name}</MenuItem>
              )}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>

          {guardianRelationOptions ?
            <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl} 
            sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
              <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Relation</InputLabel>
              <Select
                labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
                id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                // value={age}
                name="g_relationship"
                value={guardianDetailsForm.g_relationship}
                onChange={handleGuardianDeatilsInput}
                label="Relation"
              >
                {guardianRelationOptions.map(type =>
                  <MenuItem key={type.value} value={type.value}>{type.name}</MenuItem>
                )}
              </Select>
            </FormControl> : null

          }
       
         {!g_relationship} onClick={() => props.onGuardianDetails({g_relationship})}>NEXT</Button> */}
          {/* <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">NEXT</Button> */}
        </form>
      </div> )}
;
      case 2:
        return (  <div>
        <form id="form-step2" className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleGuardianDetailsSubmit} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            name="g_firstName"
            label="First Name"
            variant="outlined"
            defaultValue={guardianDetailsForm.g_firstName}
            onChange={handleGuardianDeatilsInput} />
          <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            name="g_lastName"
            label="Last Name"
            variant="outlined"
            defaultValue={guardianDetailsForm.g_lastName}
            onChange={handleGuardianDeatilsInput} />
          <TextField
            id="outlined-number"
            label="Age"
            name="g_age"
            defaultValue={guardianDetailsForm.g_age}
            type="number"
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
            onChange={handleGuardianDeatilsInput}
            variant="outlined"
          />
         
        </form>
      </div>)
;

      default:
        return 'welcome lets fill the progress.' ;
    }
  }    

  return (
   
    <div className={classes.root} align="center">

<div className = {classes.actionsContainer}>
<Paper square elevation={0}>


              <Typography>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</Typography>
              </Paper>
       
 <MobileStepper
      variant="progress"
      steps= {4}
      position="bottom"
      activeStep={activeStep}
      sx={{ minWidth: 400, flexGrow: 1 }}
      nextButton={
        <>
        <Button size="small"  onClick={handleGuardianDetailsSubmit} type="submit" 
        form={`form-step${activeStep}`}>
        {activeStep === steps.length-1? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
        </Button> 
       
       
        </>
      }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    />

     
     </div>

    </div>
  );
}



      export default User;
```

If user refreshes or reload the page, he should see the progress from where he has left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tanya

So you are saying that your user can authorize. When this happens do you receive any data about the user? Can you update the user data via POST or PUT request? If so, I'd store the active step with this data.

Assuming you have some user data that you receive when the user signs in:

```
// user - user data
export default function BuildAdStepper({user}) {
  const { activeStep: lastActiveStep, userId } = user

  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(lastActiveStep || 0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function updateActiveStep() {
      // this is just pseudo code - whatever your endpoint looks like
      await window.fetch('/yourEndpoint/:userId', { 
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify({activeStep})
      })
    }
    updateActiveStep()
  }, [activeStep])

 /* ... rest of your component * /
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to the question and helping me out at the crucial time. I am grateful to You.
basically its google login, so i get email, and name and userid. This is basically after login page sort of profile page where user fills there details. 3 steps are there at every step the form is submitted and once submitted the user cannot edit the details and simply moves ahead. Thanks once again. @aaarichter

Comment: The progress bar is starting from 0% on relogin or on page reload. Can you please suggest what to do to make the progress bar starts from where the form was left last. @aaarichter

Comment: After updating the activeStep, how to make user show which steps are completed and which are not. Its not coming. Can you please look into this? Please help its very imp part. Thanks in advance, @aaarichter

Comment: updateActiveStep is going 3 times at one go and then activeStep becomes null. please rectify this. @aaarichter